# Changing text color and image using javascript on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little problem here with on of my projects. I need that everytime the pages loads, the logo image changes and the text color of the site changes to the same color of the image. Like if the logo is black, the text color should all be black and so on. I've tried a few things and now it is working locally but when i deploy it, just one of the text color changes, the one with the class "contact". Images changes too. But the others classes remains the same. Locally, everything seems to be fine. I don't get any errors in the console. Can someone have a look what is missing? Thanks.
So here are the codes:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var colors = [
        "#CC3E2F",
        "#EDB600",
        "#1F7C61",
        "#004A6F",
        "#592D61",
        "#000000",
    ];

    var new_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    var imagens = new Array();
    imagens[0] = "./logos_cores/logo_pashisblack.svg";
    imagens[1] = "./logos_cores/logo_pashisorange.svg";
    imagens[2] = "./logos_cores/logo_pashisgreen.svg";
    imagens[3] = "./logos_cores/logo_pashisyellow.svg";
    imagens[4] = "./logos_cores/logo_pashisblue.svg";
    imagens[5] = "./logos_cores/logo_pashis_purple.svg";

    if (new_color === "#000000") {
        $(".color").css("color", new_color);
        $(".contact").css("color", new_color);
        $(".mailto").css("color", new_color);
        $(".logo__img").attr("src", imagens[0]);
    }

    if (new_color === "#CC3E2F") {
        $(".color").css("color", new_color);
        $(".contact").css("color", new_color);
        $(".mailto").css("color", new_color);
        $(".logo__img").attr("src", imagens[1]);
    }

    if (new_color === "#EDB600") {
        $(".color").css("color", new_color);
        $(".contact").css("color", new_color);
        $(".mailto").css("color", new_color);
        $(".logo__img").attr("src", imagens[3]);
    }

    if (new_color === "#1F7C61") {
        $(".color").css("color", new_color);
        $(".contact").css("color", new_color);
        $(".mailto").css("color", new_color);
        $(".logo__img").attr("src", imagens[2]);
    }

    if (new_color === "#004A6F") {
        $(".color").css("color", new_color);
        $(".contact").css("color", new_color);
        $(".mailto").css("color", new_color);
        $(".logo__img").attr("src", imagens[4]);
    }

    if (new_color === "#592D61") {
        $(".color").css("color", new_color);
        $(".contact").css("color", new_color);
        $(".mailto").css("color", new_color);
        $(".logo__img").attr("src", imagens[5]);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headlines">
            <a
                class="color"
                href="#"
                >COMING SOON</a
            > </div>
<div class="logo">
        <img
            id="logo_pashisorange.svg"
            src="./logos_cores/logo_pashisorange.svg"
            alt=""
            class="logo__img"
        />
        <h2 class="contact">
            CONTACT:
            <a class="mailto" href="mailto:hello@something.org"
                >HELLO@SOMETHING.ORG</a
            >
        </h2>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh, your JS code is the right hell... :-) JavaScript is processed in browser, so it doesn't matter if you run it locally or from remote server. Your code is working...

Comment: As @pavel stated, if your code works for you, then it should work anywhere (provided you've got jQuery properly referenced). But because your code is overly redundant, [I couldn't help but to re-write](https://jsfiddle.net/c9veh147/2/) it and show you how much more simple it could be. There is no need for any `if/then` logic.

Comment: Thanks @scott-marcus. I've tried to test your code but i don't get any images. The thing is that i need when the random math throws a color, let's say yellow, it also grabs the yellow logo. The way i wrote was the only way i could make this work.

Comment: I had a typo in my Fiddle. I've correct it and the [updated code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/m7xvbcy4/13/).

Comment: Thanks again @ScottMarcus. It worked pretty well, fantastic. But the thing is that, for example, when the random color, let's say #000000 is selected, this color must get and only get logo_pashisblack.svg. The way you helped me is showing blue color with the yellow logo, both image and color are random and not always match. That is why i used ifs but i'm not sure if it is the cleaner or reasonable way to do it. Cheers!

Comment: The issue is simply that the order that you have the colors in the colors array is the reverse order that they should be in. For example, color 0 should map to image 0. Just reverse the colors order in that array and you'll be all set.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks.It worked fine. It is just simple as embarrasing for me not thinking about the color order :) Thanks a lot! Cheers